# How deep can an inheritance tree get in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

How deep can an inheritance tree get in c#?
Let's say I have a class `A`, and I make a new class `B` that derives from `A`. Than I create a new class called `C` that derives from `B` and so on.

How many classes can I create this way that will actually be `A`?

Is there a limit to the inheritance tree?

```
public class A
{
 ...
 ...        
}

public class B:A
{
 ... 
 ...                       
}

public class C:B
{
 ...
 ...
}

public class D:C
{
 ...  
 ...
}
```

Comment: Theoretically no but there is something beautiful called Interface.

Comment: How deep do you actually need it to go.. Having an extremely deep inheritance structure would eventually end up unmaintainable.

Comment: It's the sort of question where, if you have to *ask*, you're probably already doing something wrong. (Also, the limit, if it exists, would be a .NET one, not a C# one, since classes in different languages can inherit from one another)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know there is no defined limit but i would say keep it 4-6 or at most single figure of depth , anymore would create unnecessary complexity - "Make things as simple as possible, not simpler" - Einstein .

Here is  a link you might find helpfull:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2011/05/19/code-metrics-depth-of-inheritance-dit.aspx

Happy coding

Answer (score 5):

There is no restriction in C# specification.

Most likely each implementation have some ridiculously large limit based on sizes of internal tables.

It is unlikely in normal hand written code you hit then on any platform. Auto-generated code have some chance to reach compiler/runtime limits (like method size or name length). You can try to hit limit yourself if interested - usually software limits happen to be power of 2 (like 16K/65K to start).

Answer (score 4):

There is no limit, but it's really good guideline to keep inheritance hierarchy quite simple.

There is also Code Analysis you can find on MSDN which set warning when the hierarchy is more than 4 levels deep:

> [**CA1501: Avoid excessive inheritance**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182213.aspx)
>
> **Cause**
>   A type is more than four levels deep in its inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't follow this rule. example `System.Windows.Forms.Form`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It's not a rule, it's a guideline. If you have really good reason to break the guideline you can do it.

Comment: WPF implementation is another notorious example that comes to mind regarding excessive depth of inheritance hiearchies...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is really a limit.